# Process Deluge on Linux

Tags: linux, system-administration

I tried this experiment on my Linux desktop:

```
int main()
{
  while(1)
    fork();
  return 0;
}
```

I ran this program as normal user(not root), i was surprised to find that it brought down my system, it has become unresponsive. 
I had hoped that due to resource limit exhaustion my process would have been killed,but apparently this is not the case. Any ideas why?

thanks,
Sid.

PS: this was my office Linux box on which i was experimenting from home, i hope everything 
will be okay when i restart it tomorrow ....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've re-invented a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

I think most Linux distributions don't set per-user resource limits by default. You can configure them of course, but you probably haven't.

The machine will be fine after a reboot - unless the CPU usage has caused over-heating problems.

To prevent an ordinary user from spawning too many processes you need to add configuration to [/etc/security/limits.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf)

You can use `ulimit` to set limits that would apply to your current session if you think you're going to run a program that might start too many processes or use up too much of other resources.

Comment: Douglas, is there a similar option that allows you to limit resources on an application (or specific process)?

Comment: @Dave: see setrlimit (http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) and the bash command ulimit (http://www.ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)

Comment: Thanks @Hasturkun for those links. I was aware of ulimit, but can't figure out a way to use it on a specific application. In my case I'm running OSX (it also has the ulimit) command, and would love to be able to limit resources per application, to avoid massive slowdowns.

Comment: I don't know of any way to limit it for a single application. Maybe you could wrap the binary in a script that does ulimit?

Comment: setrlimit (and ulimit by extension) sets the limits for the current process and its children, so you would wrap your application with something like (setrlimit..., exec), or (ulimit, exec) for a bash script

Answer (score 2):

you can find stuffs about that on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb#Prevention).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your system administrator didn't set up the user limits. If no user limits are set, then they can't protect anyone.